# Using native or native like components in ReactJS mobile site?

Tags: mobile, reactjs, react-native

Googling did not help so now I am here.

Now we have ReacJS and React-Native. Is there a way to create react-Native type of experience in mobile web view using reactJS? Why I want to do this? I have mobile eCommerce solution where most users come from ether google search or Facebook ad. Increasingly they come from mobile devices.

I have native app, but for shopping unless you are Amazon, Starbucks or Ebay people rarely install commerce app or keep it if they install.

What I want to build is website that looks and feels like native app, as much as possible, but is not wrapped in app install file. For those who want I can then use firebase or Cognito sync with Auth login to sync mobile and native app and deep linking to go between app and mobile view.

I mentioned React as it would seem possible avenue and I have some experience with it, but I am open to any suggestions. What ever stack used it need to work both android and IOS web views, rest I can live without.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a similar app for the web, but remember the philosophy of React is not "write once, run everywhere" but rather "learn once, write everywhere".

The browser UI tree (aka the DOM) is not identical to the iOS or Android UI tree and uses a different API. For instance, `<View />` will become `<div />`, `<TouchableHighlight />` will become `<button />`, etc.

React allows you to inject camelCased styling objects inline just like in RN, but most browser apps still use some form of CSS.

I recommend using a starter repo like this one which is already set up with Babel and hot loading with Webpack.

https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate

There will be some work involved but if you already have a working app you should be able to port it over without too much trouble.